# ASP.NET Chart control site-wide formatting

Tags: asp.net, charts, styles

Is there a way to make all charts on a site have the same look (background color, font, etc), without having to keep all of them in sync manually as the site graphic design evolves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a style class to hold all of the chart properties and then assign styles to your charts from the class.  If styles change then you can update the class and all of the charts will automatically have the updated styles.

Create a class like this:

```
public class ChartStyles {
   private System.Drawing.Color backgroundColor;
   public System.Drawing.Color BackgroundColor {
        get {return System.Drawing.Color.Blue;}
        set {backgroundColor = value;}
    }
}
```

And then assign the style to your chart:

```
Chart1.BackColor = ChartStyles.BackgroundColor;
```

It isn't the ideal solution because you still have to assign styles to each and every chart the first time the chart is created but, after that, you won't have to change a thing.